# Processing some data from PHP backend to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, setinterval

I am working on a Laravel application whereby I am to reach out to a payment gateway and listen for payment status after 5 seconds for three consecutive time. I want to pass the data from the controller to AJAX code and use setInterval Js method to perform the function.to repeatedly reach out to the API for 3 consecutive times before stopping the transaction. I have no idea of how to go around it..

**Current controller containing PHP logic**

```
 public function payFinal(Request $request)
        {

             //Convert to a JSON object
            $data =(object)$request->all();

            $quote = $request->session()->get('quoteID');

             $all = array(
                'phone' => $data->phone,
                'quote_id' => $quote,
                'payment_type' => $data->type,
            );

            //Post data to the payment gateway
            $response = $this->global_Curl($all, 'api/payment/checkout');

            //Get some data from the response from the API
            $checkID = $response->data->CheckoutRequestID;

            //Get another set of data
            $type = $data->type;

            //Add the data in an array and store in a variable ready for processing
            $data = array(
                'payment_reference' => $checkID,
                'payment_type' => $type
            );

            //Reach out to another API to get status. This set of data is to be done repeatedly
            $payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;
            if ($payStat->status === 1) {
                    return 'true';
            }
        }
```

The code below is taken from the function above and I want to pass it to AJAX and use setInterval method to repeat it

~ kindly assist..

```
//Reach out to another API to get status. This set of data is to be done repeatedly
                $payStat = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/payment/status')->data;
```

**AJAX code to fetch the data from**

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'getquote',
    type: 'get',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: '',
    success: function success(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function error(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "passing it to AJAX".  Are you calling this controller's route in an ajax method on javascript?  If so, include that code.  You seem to be asking about javascript functionality but only included php.

Comment: @Devon Okay,, let me update the code

Comment: @Devon Code updated,, am so new to AJAX,, wanted an idea of how to pass the second part of code in my question and use setInterval to set execution after every 5 seconds

Comment: I would at least give it a try before posting.  The ajax code you posted looks unrelated.  I would think recursion would be a better solution than setInterval if you're waiting for a success or failure rather than running something exactly 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

The code given is not clear..! However you can probably try like as follows.
I believe you are calling  Controller's action as ajax url from javascript and  the php function `payFinal()` is being called in that action then the following code will help you..!

JavaScript code:

```
setInterval("AJAX Function to be invoked", 5000);
```

The above code call the ajax function for every 5 second.